# App crashes when I use NSPredicate to filter my Array for my UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I am using `NSPredicate` for search record from the `tableView`.
Below is my code which I have implemented.

```
-(void)updateSearchArray:(NSString *)searchText {
    if(searchText.length==0) {
        isFilter=NO;
    } else {
        isFilter=YES;
        filteredUsers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSPredicate *resultPredicate;
        resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"displayname contains[c] %@", searchText];
        NSLog(@"%@",[tableData valueForKey:@"displayname"]);
        filteredUsers = [[tableData valueForKey:@"displayname"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
        [self.tblMemberList reloadData];

    }
}
```

My `tableData`:

```
Printing description of self->tableData:
<__NSArrayI 0x28116ba60>(
{
    displayname = Mihir;
    email = "ozam@abc.com";
    uuid = "user-97ae136";
},
{
    displayname = OzaMihir;
    email = "om@abc.com";
    uuid = "user-0c97f16";
}
)
```

My app crashes when I use above code.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key displayname.'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @anbu.Karthik It crashes filteredUsers = [[tableData valueForKey:@"displayname"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your tableData  contains array of dictionary, so in here search occur direct in the array not a string, so  use as like

```
    isFilter=YES;
    filteredUsers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   filteredUsers = [tableData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(displayname contains[c] %@)", searchText]];
    [self.tblMemberList reloadData];
```

instead of

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate;
    resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"displayname contains[c] %@", searchText];
    NSLog(@"%@",[tableData valueForKey:@"displayname"]);
    filteredUsers = [[tableData valueForKey:@"displayname"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
```

Comment: it's not working when I type O it's not showing my second record. Please see the array in my question.

Comment: I am using the same thing which you gave! Do you want me to update my Question?

Comment: My app is not crashing but only when I type "O" it's not showing the second record.

Comment: @MihirOza - if you type in `i` or `r` or `m` its shows 2 records or 1 record ... ?

Comment: You both are right Bro. Actually It was my cellForRowAtIndexPath issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code.

```
filteredUsers = [temp filteredArrayUsingPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"displayname CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText]];
[self.tblMemberList reloadData];
```

And you are passing an array of `displayname` in your code to filter it. If you want to perform the operation only on array of `displayname` array. then you can do it like below.

```
//It will perform operation/search name only on an array of `displayname`
filteredUsers = [[tableData valueForKey:@"displayname"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText]]; 
[self.tblMemberList reloadData];
```

I hope it will helpful to you.

Comment: it's not working when I type "O" it's not showing my second record. Please see the array in my question.

Comment: same problem I am facing in both the answers.

Comment: Already @Anbu.Karthik has given the same bro. It's giving weird result some times. and when I type "O" it's not showing the second record.

Comment: Glad to help you, bro.

Comment: @MihirOza If you want to perform any other operation on the array using `NSPredicate` then Follow this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206515/discussion-between-hardiks-and-mihir-oza).